# How do I avoid paragraph-tags in CKEditor5?

Tags: ckeditor

I am upgrading my CKeditor from 3 to 5, but I can't find a way to tell the ckeditor (version 5) to NOT add an extra paragraph-tag.

Do I need to disable the Paragraph-plugin? (Using removePlugins)

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What do you want instead of paragraphs? What the `enter` should do?

Comment: I don't want any paragraph-tags at the root.
This used to be an option CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false.
In Tinymce it was, if i remember correctly  forced_root_block : false

Comment: Did you happen to figure out an answer to this?  I'm trying to solve the same issue